# Where can I find configuration file for uw-imapd on debian?

Tags: debian, configuration, imap

Where can I find configuration file for uw-imapd on debian? Is there even one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, there is no configuration file for `uw-imapd`. It is known for needing very little configuration.

But according to this [link](http://pbraun.nethence.com/doc/mail/imapd.html), you should be able to change some settings by modifying `xinetd.d` configs.